# Issue with creating a sticky aside element that stays on top of div while scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

I'm trying to create a sticky aside element that stays on top of other items within the same container when scrolling. However, I'm facing some issues with the implementation.
The code below attempts to create a sticky aside element that should stay on top of other items in the container when scrolling. However, the aside element either doesn't stick or overlaps with other items.

I want the sticky aside element to stick at the top of the container and scroll with the page until it reaches the end of the container, where it should stop scrolling. It should not overlap with other items within the container.

Here's the code I've tried:

```js
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  var stickyAside = document.getElementById('sticky-aside');
  var container = stickyAside.closest('.container');
  var containerTop = container.offsetTop;
  var containerBottom = containerTop + container.offsetHeight;
  var asideHeight = stickyAside.offsetHeight;

  if (window.pageYOffset > containerBottom - asideHeight) {
    stickyAside.classList.add('sticky');
  } else {
    stickyAside.classList.remove('sticky');
  }
});
```

```css
#sticky-aside {
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
}

.row {
  position: relative;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container mt-5">
  <div class="row">
    <!-- My posts section -->
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container mt-5">
  <div class="row mt-5 border-top border-dark pt-5">
    <aside class="col-sm-4" id="sticky-aside">
      <!-- Sticky aside content -->
    </aside>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It might make solving your issue easier if you added some content to your code snippet. Currently when running it, nothing is shown but a blank page.

Comment: where is css code for 1)container 2)mt-5 3)col-sm-4 ?

Comment: it's bootstrap css

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

JS(it checks if the window's scroll position is within the container's bounds, excluding the height of the sticky aside element):

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  var stickyAside = document.getElementById('sticky-aside');
  var container = stickyAside.closest('.container');
  var containerTop = container.offsetTop;
  var containerBottom = containerTop + container.offsetHeight;
  var asideHeight = stickyAside.offsetHeight;

  if (window.pageYOffset > containerTop && window.pageYOffset < containerBottom - asideHeight) {
    stickyAside.classList.add('sticky');
  } else {
    stickyAside.classList.remove('sticky');
  }
});
```

CSS(to position the sticky aside element at the top without specifying a fixed height):

```
#sticky-aside {
  width: 100%;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you the aside tag goes as expected but it goes on top of the article and hides it instead of being on the side

Comment: What should i do?

Comment: Now it scrolls only a bit but than stops:  ```#sticky-aside {
  width: 100%;
  position: sticky;
}```

Answer (score 0):

I might be misunderstanding the question, but I believe this can all be done sans JavaScript using [`position: sticky;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#sticky).

A few things worth noting:

- The parent container cannot have an `overflow` value set
- The sticky positioned element must have some sort of orienting value (ie `top: 0;`)
- The sticky positioned element will be sticky relative to it's *parent*, not the entire page.

Hopefully the following code will help:

```css
#sticky-aside {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}
```

Comment: it works but only for a little and not the whole div this is inside.

Comment: Could you provide a more comprehensive code snippet? When I try running what you've provided I don't think it's even laying out the page as you intend. It would definitely be easier to help solve your issue if we could accurately see the problem you're having.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/bfqm44ze here's the whole page code in bootstrap

Comment: Thank you for the updated info! However, the file you provided still doesn't include all the relevant CSS to duplicate your issue.

Comment: It's bootstrap css my only custom css is: ```#sticky-aside {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}```

Comment: I think it's the section tag creating a new area