# Pinning content of div doesn't work with `position: sticky`

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

I try to pin the contents of the aside tag to the top of the `<div>` it's inside but even though I write `position: sticky; top: 0;` it doesn't work.

```html
{% extends 'main/base.html' %}

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/index.css' %}"/>
<div class="row mt-5 border-top border-dark pt-5">
  <aside class="col-sm-4 sticky-aside" id="sticky-aside">
    Aside content I want to pin to the top as the user scrolls
  </aside>
  
  <section class="col-sm-8">
    <article class="row mb-3">
      A few articles here
    </article>
  </section>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 460px) {
  .username {
    font-size: 17px;
  }
  #desc {
    font-size: 13px;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
  .card-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
}
.body {
  font-family: 'PT Serif', serif;
}
.rounded-circle {
  width: 33px;
}
.trending {
  font-family: 'Merriweather', serif !important;
  color: rgba(94, 94, 94, 0.275);
}
.border-bottom-dark{
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(41,41,41,1);
}
.aside-buttons>li{
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#sticky-aside {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}
```

```js
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  var stickyAside = document.getElementById('sticky-aside');
  var section = stickyAside.closest('section');
  var sectionTop = section.offsetTop;
  var sectionBottom = sectionTop + section.offsetHeight;
  var asideHeight = stickyAside.offsetHeight;
  if (window.pageYOffset > sectionTop && window.pageYOffset < sectionBottom - asideHeight) {
    stickyAside.classList.add('sticky');
  } else {
    stickyAside.classList.remove('sticky');
  }
});
```

When I remove the section tag it works fine but looks bad but why does the section tag ruin it? The CSS classes are Bootstrap, you can see the whole code [here](https://github.com/tugceguzle/Medium_Homepage_Clone).

I tried changing the JavaScript, putting only `position: sticky` but nothing works unless I remove the section tag.

Comment: This question looks eerily similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76280957/1469683) posted earlier today